# How to delete spaces in matrix?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

My task is to draw a coordinate system and line y+x=n, for n<=10.My code gives the correct result, but there is a condition that spaces or any other signs cannot be drawn after the line x+y=n. That is the only problem I have in solving this task and I hope you could help. I am a beginner.
(The only problem is that my code prints spaces above the line x+y=n and it should not)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    int n, i, j;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    char m[12][63] = { " " };
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++) {
            m[i][j] = ' ';
            if (i == 0 && j == 1)
                m[i][j] = '0';
            if (i == 11 && j == 61)
                m[i][j] = '2';
            if (j == 0 && i != 0 && i != 11)
                m[i][j] = '0' + 10 - i;
            if (j == 2 && i != 11)
                m[i][j] = '+';
            if (i == 11 && j % 3 == 2)
                m[i][j] = '0' + ((j - 2) / 3) % 10;
            if (i == 11 && j % 3 == 1 && j > 29 && j < 59)
                m[i][j] = '1';
            if (i == 10 && j % 3 == 2)
                m[i][j] = '+';
        }
    }
     for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){
         if((10-n+i)!=10 && (2+3*i)!=1)
        m[10-n+i][2+3*i]='*';
        }
    m[0][0]='1';
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++) {
            printf("%c", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
//n=5
 10+
 9 +
 8 +
 7 +
 6 +
 5 +
 4 +  *
 3 +     *
 2 +        *
 1 +           *
 0 +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to not print the trailing spaces on each line.  So you need to find and skip those trailing spaces rather than printing them:

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    int eol = 63;
    while (eol > 0 && m[i][eol-1] == ' ') --eol;
    for (j = 0; j < eol; j++) {
        printf("%c", m[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved. Can I just ask you for a brief explanation for this?

Comment: Pretty straight-forward -- you find the last non-space character on each line, then print just up to that character and not any of the following spaces.